# Could NOT find ZSTD (missing: ZSTD_LIBRARY ZSTD_INCLUDE_DIR)

Tags: cmake, dependencies, dwarf, zstd

I had an issue while installing [headptrack](https://github.com/KDE/heaptrack) with CMake when running `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..` in `heaptrack/build`

```
-- Could NOT find ZSTD (missing: ZSTD_LIBRARY ZSTD_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Error at 3rdparty/libbacktrace/CMakeLists.txt:160 (message):
  Could not find dwarf.h, try installing the dwarf or elfutils development
  package.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is to install the zstd dev package instead of the regular, here is the command:

```
sudo apt install -y libzstd-dev
```

The solution with the dwarf dev package for the second error:

```
sudo apt install libdwarf-dev
```

Comment: Installing libzstd-dev didn't work for me. Installing zstd was fine for me:

sudo apt install -y zstd

Comment: This does not work. I am still unable to find zstd with find_package(ZSTD REQUIRED) on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Have the same problem on OS X, this solution does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: how do you do it on windows?